# How to generate html or pdf report of executed test cases in cypress using mochawesome

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, cypress, mochawesome

I am able generate single test case report but i want to generate single report of all test case.
I generate report using **mochawesome** library.
We want to merge all report into single or full report of test cases.

> cypress.json

file code are:

```
{
  "reporter": "mochawesome",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/results",
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true
  }
}
```

package.json using code

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "delete:reports": "rm cypress/results/* || true",
    "prereport": "npm run delete:reports",
    "report": "cypress run --reporter cypress-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=reporter-config.json"
  }
}
```

But i am not able to merging report.So i need help in query :

```
npx mochawesome-merge "cypress/results/*.json" > mochawesome.json
```

> this command through error

Comment: "this command through error" -> is this the error message of the merge tool? Can you provide two json reports that must be merged? So we can play around with the merge tool. I do not have any json report here currently

Comment: please adjust the title of your post. It is not about html/pdf. it is not even about cypress, just about mocha :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are in the root directory when executing the npx merge.
Also please share what error are you getting also are individual json files getting created in cypress/results folder